# What should be hadoop.tmp.dir ?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, config

Hadoop has configuration parameter `hadoop.tmp.dir` which, as per documentation, is `*"A base for other temporary directories."* I presume, this path refers to local file system.

I  set this value to `/mnt/hadoop-tmp/hadoop-${user.name}`. After formatting the namenode and starting all services, I see exactly same path created on HDFS.

*Does this mean,  `hadoop.tmp.dir` refers to temporary location on **HDFS**?*

Comment: It's definitely for specifying a local filesystem path, not sure why it doesn't work fot you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's confusing, but `hadoop.tmp.dir` is used as the base for temporary directories locally, and also in *HDFS*. The document isn't great, but `mapred.system.dir` is set by default to `"${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/system"`, and this defines the Path on the *HDFS* where where the Map/Reduce framework stores system files.

If you want these to not be tied together, you can edit your `mapred-site.xml` such that the definition of mapred.system.dir is something that's not tied to `${hadoop.tmp.dir}`

Comment: what is the default path for **hadoop.tmp.dir**, as for Hadoop 1.2.1 ?

Comment: @ChenZhongPu its mentioned in core-site.xml

Answer (score 29):

Let me add a bit more to kkrugler's answer:

There're three HDFS properties which contain `hadoop.tmp.dir` in their values

1. `dfs.name.dir`: directory where namenode stores its metadata, with default value `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name`.
2. `dfs.data.dir`: directory where HDFS data blocks are stored, with default value `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`.
3. `fs.checkpoint.dir`: directory where secondary namenode store its checkpoints, default value is `${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/namesecondary`.

This is why you saw the `/mnt/hadoop-tmp/hadoop-${user.name}` in your HDFS after formatting namenode.

Answer (score 3):

Had a look around for information on this one. Only thing I could come up with was this post on the [Amazon Elastic MapReduce Dev Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?hadooptmpdir.html):

> In hadoop-site.xml, we set
>   hadoop.tmp.dir to
>   /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/tmp. /mnt is where
>   we mount the “extra” EC2 volumes,
>   which can contain a lot more data than
>   the default volume. (The exact amount
>   depends on instance type.) Hadoop's
>   RunJar.java (the module that unpacks
>   the input JARs) interprets
>   hadoop.tmp.dir as a Hadoop file system
>   path rather than a local path, so it
>   writes to the path in HDFS instead of
>   a local path. HDFS is mounted under
>   /mnt (specifically
>   /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/dfs/. So, you can
>   write lots of data to it.