# How to change java.io.tmpdir for spark job running on yarn

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

How can I change  `java.io.tmpdir` folder for my Hadoop 3 Cluster running on YARN?

By default it gets something like `/tmp/***`, but my `/tmp` filesystem is to small for everythingYARN Job will write there.

Is there a way to change it ?

I have also set `hadoop.tmp.dir` in `core-site.xml`, but it looks like, it is not really used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property in yarn-site.xml and restarted the cluster. After that spark stopped using /tmp file system and used directories, configured in yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs. 
java.io.tmpdir property for spark executors was also set to directories defined in yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs property.

```
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
      <value>/somepath1,/anotherpath2</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps its a duplicate of [What should be hadoop.tmp.dir ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354525/what-should-be-hadoop-tmp-dir). Also, go through all .conf's in /etc/hadoop/conf and search tmp, see if anything is hardcoded. Also specify:

- Whether you see (any) files getting created @ what you specified as hadoop.tmp.dir.
- What pattern of files are being formed @ /tmp/** after your changes are applied.

I have also noticed hive creating files in /tmp. So, you may also have a look @ hive-site.xml. Similar for any other ecosystem product you are using.

Comment: I am interested in files created by spark jobs running on yarn. I can see this in command line of the processes that yarn runs. The pattern looks like /tmp/hadoop-username/***. I have configured  hadoop.tmp.dir in core-site.xml. The problem is, that this has not helped.